# Unable to close all opened Windows

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have a scenario where two Windows, A and B, are opened. Window B is opened from a button in Window A. After running the code, I want both Windows to be closed by using Webdriver. As expected, only Window A cannot be closed after running the code. Here is the code that is intended to do carry out this operation.

```
Set <String> allhandles = 
  driver.getWindowHandles(); // get all opened windows' handle
String window_B = 
  driver.getWindowHandle(); //get the handle for Window B    
for(String all_handles:allhandles){ 
  if(!all_handles.equals(window_B)){
    driver.close(); //close Window B
  }
  String window_A = driver.getWindowHandles().toString();
  driver.switchTo().window(window_A);
  driver.close();   
}
```

Also, the error message stated that it could not find Window A, although it did state the correct handle.

Comment: Shouldn't you use the `quit()` method instead of close to close all instances of the browser.

Comment: @demouser123, sorry I missed your comment. Yours work too. Thannks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To close all windows (in arbitrary order) use this code:

```
      for (String handle : allhandles) { 
        driver.switchTo().window(handle);
        driver.close();   
      }
```

There are some flaws in your code:

```
  if(!all_handles.equals(window_B)){
    driver.close(); //close Window B
  }
```

This does *not* close window B (as the comment suggests) unless window B happens to be the active one (but in this case the `if` statement is useless). Moreover, the variable name `all_handles` is misleading, as it is just one handle from the set of `allhandles`.

This line

```
String window_A = driver.getWindowHandles().toString();
```

does not return the name of window A (as the varaible name suggests) but a String representation of the `Set<java.lang.String>` object. This is a huge difference and switching to this will inevitably lead to an error (saying something like "window does not exist").

Comment: @lamchiomeng I added some details in order to answer your questions in your edit comment. Hope it helped.

Comment: yeap it did. Really appreciate the clarification. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use this below method to kill the process 
example calling the method : killProcess("firefox")

```
public static void killProcess(String processName) throws IOException {

    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /f /im " + processName + ".exe");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, really appreciate it. I decided to go with Würgspaß's solution as it is more suitable to my codes in general. But I shall also try out your solution as it is good to know more methods out there.